# Get values of tensors in loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, theano, pytorch

I would like to get the values of the **y_pred** and **y_true** tensors of this [keras backend function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py). I need this to be able to perform some custom calculations and change the loss, these calculations are just possible with the real array values.

```
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    #some code here
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

There is a way to do this in keras? Or in any other ML framework (tf, pytorch, theano)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in general you can't compute the loss that way, because Keras is based on frameworks that do automatic differentiation (like Theano, TensorFlow) and they need to know which operations you are doing in between in order to compute the gradients of the loss.

You need to implement your loss computations using `keras.backend` functions, else there is no way to compute gradients and optimization won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this within the loss function:
y_true = keras.backend.print_tensor(y_true, message='y_true')

Following is an excerpt from the Keras documentation (https://keras.io/backend/):

print_tensor
keras.backend.print_tensor(x, message='')
Prints message and the tensor value when evaluated.

Note that print_tensor returns a new tensor identical to x which should be used in the later parts of the code. Otherwise, the print operation is not taken into account during evaluation.